# How to return the number of times a string with specific requirements appears in a list?

Tags: python, custom-lists

Given a list of strings, return the count of the number of strings where the string length is 3 or more and the first and last chars of the string are the same.

To solve this problem I created the following function,

```
def match_ends(words):
  FirstL=words[0:1]
  LastL=words[-1:]
  x=len(words)>3 and FirstL == LastL
  count=0
 for x in words:
    count+=1
    return count
```

then tested it here,

```
def test(got, expected):
  if got == expected:
    prefix = ' OK '
  else:
    prefix = '  X '
  print ('%s got: %s expected: %s' % (prefix, repr(got), repr(expected)))


# Calls the above functions with interesting inputs.
def main():
  print ('match_ends')
  test(match_ends(['abaa', 'xyzax', 'aa', 'x', 'bbb']), 3)
  test(match_ends(['', 'x', 'xy', 'xyx', 'xx']), 1)
  test(match_ends(['aaa', 'be', 'abc', 'hello']), 1)


  print
```

Result:

```
X  got: 1 expected: 3
OK  got: 1 expected: 1
OK  got: 1 expected: 1
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your best bet here is to use a list comprehension.  A list comprehension has three parts:

- The transformation that you want to perform on each element of the input,
- the input itself, and
- an optional "if" statement that indicates when to produce output

So for example, we can say

```
[ x * x               # square the number
for x in range(5) ]  # for each number in [0,1,2,3,4]  `
```

which will produce the list

```
[0 1 4 9 16]
```

We can add a third (filtering) line, and get only odd numbers back:

```
[x * x
for x in range(5) 
if x % 2]     # divide x by 2, take the remainder -- if 1, output the number`
```

In your particular case, we don't care about the transformation part.  We just want to output the word if it fits your criteria:

```
[word
 for word in word_list
 if len(word) >= 3 and word[0] == word[-1] ]
```

This will give you a list back.  Now you just need to get the length of that list:

```
len( [word
 for word in word_list
 if len(word) >= 3 and word[0] == word[-1] ]  )
```

Want to turn that into a function?  Here you go:

```
def count_matching_words(word_list):
    return len([word
                for word in word_list
                if len(word) >= 3 and word[0] == word[-1]])
```

Comment: While I approve of the way you broke this down, I must protest against splitting up your list comprehensions this way. This code can be clear even if condensed into one line - about the only time multiline list comprehensions should happen is when the run the risk of exceeding 72 characters per line.

Comment: As someone who has been teaching Python professionally for more than 10 years, I strongly disagree. List comprehension syntax consistently baffle newcomers (and not-so-newcomers) to the language, and I've found that breaking them down in this way dramatically helps them to understand what's going on.  The moment that I started (about two years ago) to write my list comprehensions in this way, my students' understanding improved a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here:

1. When you're looping over each of the words, you `return` `count` within the loop, instead of at the end when the loop finishes. This is why you were always getting `1`.
2. You *always* `count += 1` even if `x` is `False`.
3. `x` is taking the first and last item of the list, rather than the first and last letter in each word in the list.
4. Finally you shadow the `bool` `x` in your `for` loop.

---

**Tips**

Why not split this into two functions?

```
def match_end(word):
    first, last = word[0], word[-1:]
    return True if first == last and len(word) >= 3 else False

def match_ends(words):
    count = 0
    for word in words:
        count += 1 if match_end(word) else 0
    return count
```

The first function, `match_end(word)` returns a `bool` of either `True` or `False`.

- First, It sets the variables `first` and `last` to the first and last letter of the string via slicing.
- Next, it `return`s `True` if the first letter is the same as the last, and if the length of the word is less than three. Otherwise, it `return`s `False`. This is done with Python's [Ternary Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator).

The second function, `match_ends(words)`, takes in a list of strings(like your original one) iterates over each word in the `list`.

- For each word in the list, it tests to see if `match_end(word)` returns `True`.

  - If so, it increments the count by `1`.
  - Otherwise, it does nothing (increments count by `0`).
- Finally, it returns `count`.